# Android inflate assets vs setContentView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-inflate

I've noticed that you can accomplish better looking / more complicated view transitions by inflating a view and discarding (or saving) the previous view. However, I'm under the assumption that `setContentView` and `startActivity` do a better job at conserving memory while switching views. Is there a recommendation for what to use where?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/09/inflation-is-a-good-thing/
It can be start point in your quest.